# Linking checkbox to list item in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, checkbox, sharepoint

I have a list element `Scholarship` in Sharepoint of type "Yes/No (Checkbox)".

[image: Scholarship element]

So, I created a checkbox via Vue.js:

```
<div class="row">
       <div class="d-inline col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
          <b>Scholarship Player</b>
       </div>
       <div class="d-inline col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6"> {{ this.players.Scholarship }} 
          <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" v-model="Scholarship"> </div>
       </div>
```

[image: Checkbox]

The problem I'm having is that it shows me the checkbox and next to it "true". When I change the list element to false, it will show me "false" and the checkbox will remain the same. This means that it didn't link the list element "Scholarship" to the checkbox.

How can I link/connect my list element with the checkbox? (Meaning that **when the checkbox is checked, the list element will be true** and whenever the checkbox is not checked it will be false)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at the code, the value you're displaying isn't the same as the v-model. Also, you don't need "this." in the template section.

```
<div class="d-inline col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6"> {{ players.Scholarship }} 
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" v-model="players.Scholarship"> </div>
</div>
```